# Replacing value in different worksheet

Tags: vba, replace, find, vlookup

I have a problem and can't seem to solve it. I spend hours to try and fix it, but I can't seem to get passed the errors. Probably it is really simple for you to fix.

If you can help me, that would be amazing. I need a VBA-code to replace value X (cell found with vlookup) with a value in a different worksheet.

In the sheet: **Voorraadmutatie doorvoeren** I have a value in cell D4 that corresponds with a location in the sheet **Voorraadbeheer stelling(en)** (see images).

The value in cell D16 is the **new** stock so the stock in the database needs to change after activating the macro. However, to find the right cell to change I need to vlookup the right row/cell.

[Sheet voorraadmutatie doorvoeren](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVub1.png)

[Sheet Voorraadbeheer stelling(en)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLeaf.png)

If you could help me, that would be amazing. I have tried many things but I am not trained in using VBA. I keep getting errors and can't seem to solve it by browsing on the internet.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this example can help

```
  Sub vLookup()
 
    Dim SearchedValue, oldStock, newStock As Variant
    Dim MyMatrix As Range
    Dim No_index_col As Single
    Dim ApproximateValue As Boolean
    Dim n As Long
    
    ' SearchedValue = "D002"
    SearchedValue = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("voorraadmutatie doorvoeren").Range("D4")
    ' new stock in D16
    newStock = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("voorraadmutatie doorvoeren").Range("D16")
    
    Set MyMatrix = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("voorraadbeheer stelling(en)").Range("A:C")
    No_index_col = 3
    ApproximateValue = False
    ' display the previous vlue of the stock
    oldStock = Application.WorksheetFunction.vLookup(SearchedValue, MyMatrix, No_index_col, ApproximateValue)
    
    n = 2 '2nd ligne of the matrix
    Do While Not (IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Application.Sheets("voorraadbeheer stelling(en)").Cells(n, 1)))

        If ThisWorkbook.Application.Sheets("voorraadbeheer stelling(en)").Cells(n, 1) = SearchedValue Then
 
            ThisWorkbook.Application.Sheets("voorraadbeheer stelling(en)").Cells(n, 3) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("voorraadmutatie doorvoeren").Range("D16").Value
 
        End If
        ' next line
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! With the above example I got a lot further. The msgbox presents the quantity/number I need to replace with the new quantity in cell D16. Now I still need to figure out how I replace the adress of the value from the msgbox with the value in cell D16.

Comment: instead of msgBox add `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet voorraadmutatie doorvoeren").Range("D16").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.vLookup(SearchedValue, MyMatrix, No_index_col, ApproximateValue)`.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you very much Jesin. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Ok. Somehow the first test was succesful. Now it runs the wrong way. It returns the data from the vlookup to D16 while the value of D16 has to be placed in the cell which is found by vlookup. I know I am very bad at this, trying to learn

Comment: I add some modification in the code to replace the new value of the stok in the matrix (see above)

Comment: Thank you very much Jestin. You have really helped me.